# Testing for statistical significance between two dependent (unpaired) groups

Tags: t-test, bootstrap

I'm currently conducting some research on inflation perceptions and I have two groups of data (Group 1 with 67 responses, Group 2 with 71 responses). Group 1 were asked question x, and Group 2 asked question y (both questions essentially were what do you think the current inflation rate is, just asked in different ways). I then want to test if these groups are statistically different where my null would be no difference in means. I planned to do a t-test on this, but due to sampling limitations the data is neither random nor independent (some respondents may be from the same households etc and they are then randomly allocated to question x or y). It also is not homogenous in variance. However, a dependent t-test is not appropriate as there is no pairing of the data. What is the best method to test this? (I'm aware there won't be a perfect solution due to the non-random sampling issue, I'm just looking for the most robust method possible).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no formal test available for all the reasons you mention.  Robust methods, in any sense of "robust," will be no cure for those problems.  IMHO, the best you can do is describe the data clearly and appropriately, either with statistical summaries, graphics, or both.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you